# What does `actix-web` use a provided `tokio` runtime for?

Tags: rust, actix-web

The documentation for `actix_web::HttpServer::run()` says

> This method starts a number of HTTP workers in separate threads. [...] One worker set is created for each socket address to be bound. [...]
>
> This methods panics if [...] no Tokio runtime is set up.

So, if `actix_web` creates dedicated worker threads anyway to handle client requests, what does it need the outer Tokio runtime for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The provided Tokio runtime is used to run the internal TCP server that listens for and accepts connections before the HTTP requests are parsed and processed on Actix Web's worker threads. See the [actix-server](https://crates.io/crates/actix-server) crate.

Answer (score 0):

Actix_web depends on [actix_rt](https://docs.rs/actix-rt/latest/actix_rt/) to create the threads. Each of those threads is actually a single-threaded Tokio runtime, not a thread in the operating system sense of the word.

Comment: Exactly my point: `actix_web` uses `actix_rt` internally to create the Tokio runtimes it needs. So, why does it *additionally* depend on an externally provided Tokio runtime?